# What is the differnce between asyncio.coroutime and types.coroutine decorators?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

Practicing writing `coroutines` in python 3.6,
Noticed that both in:

```
from asyncio import coroutine
```

And in:

```
from types import coroutine
```

There are 2 decorators which on first glance do the same..

Reading the documentation of first(from `asyncio`)

> Decorator to mark coroutine

And the second one (from `types`):

> Convert regular generator function to coroutine.

Confused me even more..
I know i can use `async yield from` in python3.6, so i get lost to really  understand the difference between the two.

Please assist

Comment: You can see the two implementations: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py#L104, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/types.py#L237. `asyncio.coroutine` *uses* `types.coroutine`.

Answer (score 2):

With the advent of `async def` syntax, both decorators are rarely used, and `asyncio.coroutine` is officially [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine).

The `types.coroutine` decorator is still useful as a low-level tool for creating a coroutine out of a generator. That kind of thing is useful when crafting primitives for a custom event loop implementation. With `@types.coroutine` you can create a coroutine out of a barebones generator, whose `yield` yields a value of your choice directly to the event loop.

For example, a `sleep` coroutine implementation could look like this:

```
@types.coroutine
def sleep(delay):
    deadline = time.time() + delay
    yield 'sleep_until', deadline
```

This creates a coroutine similar to the one created with `async def`, but with the magic ability to communicate with a compatible event loop, which might contain code like this:

```
def run(self):
    while self._to_run:
        coro = self._to_run.popleft()
        try:
            cmd, arg = coro.send(None)
        except StopIteration:
            continue
        if cmd == 'sleep_until':
            self._to_wake[arg] = coro
    time.sleep(min(self._to_wake) - time.time())
    self._to_run.extend(coro for t, coro in self._to_wake.items()
                        if t <= time.time())
```

For more details see [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) by David Beazley where a full-featured event loop is built in front of a live audience. (Don't be put off by the use of `yield from` - the newer `async def` works exactly the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 3.5+ you don't need to think about it.

Modern way to create coroutine is to define it with `async def`. If you're using recent Python version just follow relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines).

---

If you interested in retrospective:

`asyncio.coroutine` decorator is an old way to create coroutine people used before Python 3.5.

`types.coroutine` is just [an utility function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.coroutine) mostly used internally in Python. As jonrsharpe noted `asyncio.coroutine` uses `types.coroutine` in its implementation. It's a strange thing it happened to be public, I've never seen anybody used it. You probably shouldn't also :)